# Django: modelchoicefield with multiple modelfields

Tags: python, django

I would like to request some assistance regarding this matter,
I am fairly new to django and I like it so far.

I have the following model:

```
class Courses_list(models.Model):
    Abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    Course = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

     def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.Abbreviation = self.Abbreviation.upper()
        super(Courses_list, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

     def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.Abbreviation

class Job_Posting(models.Model):
    Job_Position = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Job_Position

class Educational_Requirement(models.Model):
    fkey = models.ForeignKey('Job_Posting')
    Course = models.ForeignKey('Courses_list')
```

And form:

```
class CustomField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return obj.Course

class SampleForm(ModelForm):
    COURSE = CourseField(queryset=Educational_Requirement.objects.all())
```

I am saving at:

```
class MyModel(ModelForm):
    course = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = True, blank = True)
```

In the frontend of my test app `SampleForm` shows the `Course` as choices but how do I get the actual value of `Course` and save it? Because when I view my saved `COURSE` in the admin it displays `Educational_Requirement Object` instead of the value I have seen on the dropdown. I can't use `__unicode__` at `Educational_Requirement` as it would raise an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated my answer based on your updated question.

Why not use a ManyToManyField and let Django's ORM handle the educational_requirement relationship for you? This way you can use Django's reverse lookup to handle the ForeignKey's name.

```
class Courses_list(models.Model):
    Abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    Course = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.Abbreviation = self.Abbreviation.upper()
        super(Courses_list, self).save(force_insert, force_update)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.Abbreviation

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Course'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Courses'

class Job_Posting(models.Model):
    Job_Position = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, unique=True)
    educational_requirement = models.ManyToManyField(Courses_list)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Job_Position

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Job Position'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Job Positions'
```

Comment: I do have that Meta class but I can't add the `title` field as it would defeat the purpose of why I needed it as that.

Comment: Oops, I understood it wrong, let me update the post, sorry about that

Comment: Also a side note, I'd recommend not using the same name for a field as your model. It can get very confusing, especially with reverse lookups.

Comment: I see, I have read the documentation and It's kind of confusing to me as how I would query it. How does it behave as it is really not saved in the database(I saw no field referring to `educational_requirement `) Can I have an example where I can get all `educational_requirement` under a certain `Job_Posting`? Many thanks.

Comment: Django will create a table named `appName_Job_Posting_Courses_list` which would have three fields: `id`, `Job_Posting_id`, and `educational_requirement_id`. To query all requirements for a Job Posting, you'd do: `posting = Job_Posting.objects.get(pk=some_id)` to get your posting. Then to get that posting's educational requirements, you could say `for requirement in posting.educational_requirements.all: print(requirement)`